# Como receber por parâmetro um array de objetos de outra classe no Java?

Tags: java

Olá pessoal minha dúvida é de que estou tentando receber por parâmetro um array de objetos de outra classe,para a classe que quero colocar os array por parâmetro.

As classes são : **Percurso e Custos**

Eu tenho que receber por parâmetro um array de objetos do tipo Percurso,pra depois poder calcular.Aqui está o código :

Classe **Percurso** :

```
public class Percurso {

    private double kmPercorrida;
    private double valorCombustivel;
    private double valorPedagio;

    public Percurso() {
        this(0,0,0);
    }

    public Percurso(double kmPercorrida, double valorCombustivel,
            double valorPedagio) {

        this.kmPercorrida = kmPercorrida;
        this.valorCombustivel = valorCombustivel;
        this.valorPedagio = valorPedagio;
    }
```

Classe **Custos** :

```
public class Custos {

    public String calcularViagem(Percurso [] p ) {



        return "";


    }

}
```

Na parte **Percurso [] p**,preciso passar os array do objeto Percurso,com as variáveis **kmPercorrida,valorCombustivel,valorPedagio**.

OBS : No return eu só deixei assim para não aparecer problemas,depois eu altero.

Como posso fazer isso ? Se alguém souber por favor me ajude.
E desculpem me se o formato do post estiver errado,sou novo aqui no fórum.Eu já li também como fazer um post decente,mas mesmo assim qualquer erro,por favor me avisem que eu arrumo.

Comment: Não entendi qual sua dúvida, parece estar tudo certo, ainda que em um código real seria um erro ter valor monetário como `double`.

Comment: A minha dúvida é de que quero através deste array colocar as variáveis da outra classe(Percurso) para poder retorna depois.Pois é o que o exercício pede.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Custos {

  public String calcularViagem(Percurso[] percursos) {
  return "";
  }

}
```

Comment: Obrigado também pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

Pra declarar um array em Java seria `Percurso[] p`, e não `Percurso p[]`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo por me corrigir,mas mesmo assim ainda estou com dúvida de como receber através do parâmetro as variáveis da outra classe,para que eu possa calcular.

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, quer saber como acessar as variáveis dos objetos desse array?

Comment: Sim exatamente,estou querendo colocar as variáveis da outra classe nesse array.